# Enable HTTPS in the ExternalTaskClient of Camunda

Tags: java, ssl, https, camunda

Hello fellow camunda user,  currently I am developing on a project in which I am using the [External Task Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.bpm/camunda-external-task-client/1.3.1) from Camunda.

I asked myself if there is any possibility to let the ExternalTaskClient use Https ?

I took a look at the Jar and couldn't find any hints on how to deal with this problem. I saw that the code prevents a RequestExecutor that initializes its HttpClient via the HttpClientBuilder from Apache.

```
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom()
  .useSystemProperties()
  .addInterceptorLast(requestInterceptorHandler);
this.httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
```

I took another look at the [Documentation for interceptors and basic authentication](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/ext-client/#basic-authentication) and thought that I could realize Https via a CustomInterceptor. But the CustomInterceptor just adds additional information to the http header.

Afterwards I started searching again and found the following [Question about supporting HTTPS](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-external-task-client-java/issues/28). Reading through the comments I saw a [Pull Request](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-external-task-client-java/pull/38) that dealt mainly with the customization of the Apache HttpClient and its creation in the RequestExecutor. The PR was never merged...

To cut a long story short, does the ExternalTaskClient support Https ? (even though with workaround)

Best regards
Thomas

**Edit:**
I extended my class called SSLExternaTaskClientWrapper from the ExternalTaskClientBuilderImpl, overwrote the initEngineClient() Method and instantiated a wrapper for the RequestExecutor that extended from RequestExecutor and overwrote the initialization of the Apache HttpClient. Just like 'mnowrot' in [this thread](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-external-task-client-java/issues/28) said. Instead of calling ExternalTaskClient.create() for creating a new ExternalTaskClient I instantiate my SSLExternalTaskClientWrapper.

Pros:

- It is possible to set a HTTP client with SSL/TLS context

Cons:

- Maintenance for every update of the ExternalTaskCLient
- If the HttpClient gets private and/or the initHttpClient() method gets private this solution is ready for the garbage, meaning that it is pretty vulnerable.

Summing this up I have to say that i don't see the external task client in some productive environment until it can perform requests over Https. Seems like I have to fetch and pull on my own.

My question still remains :)